# RTSP audio streaming is not working with wifi but does work with mobile network

Tags: android, rtsp

I am using following code to play rtsp stream using media player.

```
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(streamurl);
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();
```

It plays fine on Mobile Network. But in wifi it is not playing, and shows error while preparing media player. Why it is? Does anyone know the solution for it?

Answer (score 3):

RTSP (RTP/UDP) works like this

1) Session Management on TCP layer

2) Media on UDP layer

If you don't have the NAT correctly done on your wifi network the UDP traffic may not be received to the device.

In this case

1) Device tries to fall back to RTSP tunneling over TCP.
2) If the streaming server doesn't support RTP over TCP the device will fail to stream

Solution 1
Configure our Wifi router to NAT the UDP ports to your device. I am not certain which ports you can try 1024-65355

Solution 2
Find a streaming server which allow RTP over TCP

Your Mobile network might not be doing any NATing or it is doing smart NATing which doesn't break RTSP

Answer (score 0):

mediaplayer can not play if streamurl start with "rtsp://blahblah.com/blah.3gp" on wifi.
change streamurl  "http://blahblah"